# The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String in Android app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fetch database stored values and checking if ANY of the values exist then  a method should be called.However, while checking I am getting this error--> The operator `||` is undefined for the argument type(s) `java.lang.String`, java.lang.String

```
if ((DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_COUNTRY
    || DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_WORLD) != null)
{
    populate();
}
```

Comment: Try `DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_COUNTRY != null||DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_WORLD !=null`

Comment: @Sebastian, You should really have made this an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You miss the boolean expression in the first part of "if":

`DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_COUNTRY` and `DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_WORLD` are not boolean

You can use logical operators like `||`, `&&`, etc. only with the boolean types.

Try comparing each value with "null" separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_COUNTRY != null || DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_WORLD != null)
{
  populate();
}
```

In Java, you can use `boolean` operations only to `boolean`s. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_COUNTRY != null || DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_WORLD != null)
{
 populate();
}
```

You can use logical operators like `||` and &`&` only with the boolean values. As `DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_COUNTRY` and `DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_WORLD` are both Strings, Java doesn't know what to do with them when you add the `||` operator to it. You'll need to compare them to null individually.

Answer (score 1):

If those are strings, you want to do this:

```
if (DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_COUNTRY != null ||
    DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_WORLD != null)
{
    // executes if at least one of the values is not null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this.

```
if (DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_COUNTRY != null
    || DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_WORLD != null)
{
    populate();
}
```

You can't use `||` when you use String. You can use this only for boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_COUNTRY ) || (DBAdapter.KEY_AUDIENCE_TARGETING_WORLD ))
{
  populate();
}
```

Try this if it works

Comment: From the compiler error, it's clear that those fields are `String` values. Your code isn't going to compile any better than OP's original code.